# React - Unknown Props even though they exist in response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

I am having issues with rendering some data from an API, due to an error I am receiving in the browser console.

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Unknown props `scriptVersionId`, `configVersionId`, `model`, `manufacturer`, `refSubType` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

Now I know this has been asked multiple times, but I cannot find a concrete answer. I am a newbie to React after coming from a Java background.

So the way this works is as follows:

Parent component loads the data from API:

```
  loadApplicableConfigsForDevice = (type, currentConfig) => {
    if (type != null && currentConfig != null) {
        console.log(type);
        console.log(currentConfig);
        deviceApi.getConfigs(type, currentConfig)
            .then(availableConfigs => {
                console.log("Response Data " + availableConfigs);
                this.setState({availableConfigs})
            })
    }
}
```

This loads the data as expected and the response in the browser is as follows:

```
[ 
{ 
"name":"Hard Wired - LMU 2630 - Driver ID Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":41,
"configVersionId":12,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":200,
"configVersionId":33,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":200,
"configVersionId":33,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - Large Van Config",
"scriptVersionId":201,
"configVersionId":17,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - Small Van Config",
"scriptVersionId":202,
"configVersionId":16,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":220,
"configVersionId":12,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":220,
"configVersionId":12,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Car Config",
"scriptVersionId":220,
"configVersionId":12,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Large Van Config",
"scriptVersionId":221,
"configVersionId":10,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Small Van Config",
"scriptVersionId":222,
"configVersionId":11,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
},
{ 
"name":"OBD - LMU 3030 - VBus- Small Van Config",
"scriptVersionId":222,
"configVersionId":11,
"description":"OBD",
"model":"LMU 3030",
"manufacturer":"CalAmp",
"refSubType":"OBD"
}
]
```

So i know the API Call is working, as it is fetching the data. As you can see I then `setState` with the `availableConfigs` returned from the response.

I then pass the availableConfigs from state down int a child component:

```
 render() {
    const { availableConfigs } = this.state

 return (
 <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column width={10}>
                    <EventStatistics
                        device={device} />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column width={6}>
                    <DeviceInfo device={device} configs={availableConfigs} handleDeviceUpdate={this.updateDevice} userPreferences={userPreferences} />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
```

In the child components render method, I then get the props 
    `const { device, userPreferences, configs } = this.props;`

And then pass that value into a dropdown object

```
<Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Configuration Version' />
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Dropdown
                                loading={settingConfig}
                                disabled={!configEditable}
                                placeholder='Set Config Version'
                                options={configs}
                                value={formatConfigName( device )}
                                onChange={this.handleConfigChange} />
                            <EditButton editingEnabled={configEditable} onClick={this.toggleConfigEdit} />
                            {/*{formatConfigName( device )}*/}
                        </Table.Cell>
```

Notice I pass `{configs}` to the options part of the dropdown.

The issue is that the options are not showing in the dropdown, due to the error mentioned at the start. My state in the parent component looks as follows:

```
 state = {
    device: {},
    events: []
}
```

I know this maybe simple for some people, but I have been banging my head with this issue for hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**EDIT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Table, Label, Dropdown, Button, Segment, Divider, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'

import { getAllSimGroups } from 'api/commonApi'
import { setSimGroup, getConfigs } from 'api/deviceApi'
import { formatDate } from 'utils/commonUtils'
import { formatConfigName } from 'utils/deviceUtils'

import { SendCommand } from 'areas/customer-management'
import { PermissionWrapper } from 'common/ui'
import { IssueWizard } from "common/issue-wizard";

class DeviceInfo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        simGroups: [],
        configs: [],
        simGroupEditable: false,
        settingSimGroup: false,
        configEditable: false,
        settingConfig: false
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    getAllSimGroups()
        .then( simGroups => simGroups.map( formatSimGroup ) )
        .then( simGroups => this.setState( { simGroups } ) )
}


toggleSimGroupEdit = () => this.setState( { simGroupEditable: !this.state.simGroupEditable } );

handleSimGroupChange = ( e, data ) => {
    console.log("Configs " + this.state.configs);
    this.setState( { settingSimGroup: true, simGroupEditable: false } );
    const { imei, iccid } = this.props.device;
    setSimGroup( imei, iccid, data.value )
        .then( this.props.handleDeviceUpdate )
        .catch( error => toast.error( error.message ) )
        .then(() => this.setState( { settingSimGroup: false } ) )
};

handleConfigChange = ( e, data ) => {
    console.log( data.value );
    console.log("Configs " + this.state.configs);
    this.setState( { settingConfig: true, configEditable: false } );
    // const {type, config.name} = this.props.device;
    getConfigs(this.props.device.type, this.props.device.config.name)
        .then( this.props.handleDeviceUpdate )
        .catch( error => toast.error( error.message ) )
        .then(() => this.setState( { settingConfig: false } ) )
};

toggleConfigEdit = () => this.setState( { configEditable: !this.state.configEditable } );

render() {
    const { simGroupEditable, simGroups, settingSimGroup, configEditable, settingConfig } = this.state;
    const { device, userPreferences, configs } = this.props;
    const simGroupCode = device.simGroup != null ? device.simGroup.code : 'SimGroup Not Set';

    return (
        <Segment raised>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column width={8}>
                        <PermissionWrapper responsibilities={userPreferences.responsibilities} responsibility='SEND_SMS' >
                            <SendCommand iccid={device.iccid} />
                        </PermissionWrapper>
                    </Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={3}></Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={5}>    
                        <IssueWizard
                            id={device.imei}
                            context='IN_USE'
                            type='DEVICE'
                            trigger={<Button content="Check Device for Issues" size='large' />} 
                        />
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
            <Divider />

            <Table size='small' compact singleLine verticalAlign='middle'>
                <Table.Body>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Vehicle Reg' />
                        <Table.Cell>{device.vehReg}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='IMEI' />
                        <Table.Cell>{device.imei}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='First Message' />
                        <Table.Cell>{formatDate( device.activationDate )}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Last Message' />
                        <Table.Cell>{formatDate( device.lastMessageTime, 'HH:mm DD MMMM YYYY' )}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Service ID' />
                        <Table.Cell>{device.serviceId}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='ICCID' />
                        <Table.Cell>{device.iccid}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Sim Group' />
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Dropdown
                                loading={settingSimGroup}
                                disabled={!simGroupEditable}
                                placeholder='Set Sim Group'
                                options={simGroups}
                                value={settingSimGroup ? 0 : simGroupCode}
                                onChange={this.handleSimGroupChange} />
                            <EditButton editingEnabled={simGroupEditable} onClick={this.toggleSimGroupEdit} />
                        </Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Configuration Status' />
                        <Table.Cell>{device.config ? device.config.status : ''}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <InfoHeader name='Configuration Version' />
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Dropdown
                                loading={settingConfig}
                                disabled={!configEditable}
                                placeholder='Set Config Version'
                                options={configs}
                                value={formatConfigName( device )}
                                onChange={this.handleConfigChange} />
                            <EditButton editingEnabled={configEditable} onClick={this.toggleConfigEdit} />
                            {/*{formatConfigName( device )}*/}
                        </Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </Segment>
    )
}
}

export default DeviceInfo

const InfoHeader = ( { name } ) => (
<Table.Cell width={6}>
    <Label className='fluid text-center' size='medium' color='blue' content={name} />
</Table.Cell>
);

const EditButton = ( { onClick, editingEnabled } ) => (
<Button
    compact
    size='mini'
    negative={editingEnabled}
    floated='right'
    content={editingEnabled ? 'Cancel' : 'Edit'}
    onClick={onClick} />
  );

// const formatConfig = conf => ( { key: conf.name, text: formatConfigName( conf ), value: formatConfigName( conf ) } );

const formatSimGroup = sg => ( { key: sg.id, text: sg.name, value: sg.code } )
```

Comment: Is `DeviceInfo` a component you've written?

Comment: Yes it is a component ive written

Comment: Can you include that code? The attributes from available configs are being added to a `div` and these aren't valid props for a `div`. This is why you are getting this error

Comment: Ive edited my answer with that component

Comment: I can't see the offending line here & I'm a bit lost in the hierarchy of these components. You should follow the `config` value down through the components until you find where it's being passed to `div` to handle this.  https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Comment: This is sort of the point. I dont know where this `div` is coming from. In the edited answer, find `<InfoHeader name='Configuration Version' />` and then `{configs}` is passed into `options` of the `semantic-ui-react` dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/.

In here the options prop is specified to be

> Array of Dropdown.Item props e.g. `{ text: '', value: '' }`

See https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/ for allowed keys in each option item.

**In summary: you have to convert your configs object before giving it to the Dropdown component as options.**

Something like this might work:

```
options={configs.map( config => {text:config.name, value: config})}
```